# Hágase ver del médico

Tags: preposiciones, reflexivos, voz-pasiva

This line is from *El coronel no tiene quien le escriba* by Gabriel García Márquez.

> —Compadre, hágase ver **del** médico.

I have several questions about it.

First of all, is *hacerse ver **del** médico* a common expression for *get oneself examined by a/the doctor*?

If the bold part was left blank and I was asked to fill it in, I would probably put *por*. Would it also be correct?

> Hágase ver **por** el médico.

Is this construction `hacerse V de N` generally applicable to `get oneself V-ed by N`, or is the use of *de* specific to this expression?

Does it also work with a proper noun? (I have a feeling it doesn't.)

> Hágase ver del doctor García.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The preposition "de" is indeed one that is broadly, and therefore often loosely used in the language. One of the uses is locative. This use is rather colloquial, for example:

1. Fui **del** médico (short for: Fui a lo del médico, I went to the doctor's place).

Therefore, the sentence:

2. Hágase ver **del** médico.

can be understood as short for: Hágase ver en lo del médico, Go and get yourself checked up at the doctor's office, or Vaya al médico a hacerse ver, Go to the doctor's to have yourself checked up).

The sentence turns out to be equivalent to:

3. Hágase ver **por** el médico.

but I find (3) to be clearer as to who will conduct the medical examination. With (2), it might be the case that the person goes to the doctor's and is examined by a nurse.

As regards the use of a proper name:

4. Hágase ver **del** doctor García.

I find it to be as good as (2) and, therefore, functionally equivalent to:

5. Hágase ver **por** el doctor García.

subject to the same distinction made above (in (4) the adjunct is merely locative, while in (5) the agent's identity is more specific).

Answer (score 0):

Cuestión: — Compadre, hágase ver del médico.

### *Explicando las sutilezas del lenguaje*

1.-  ¿Es "*hacerse ver del médico*" una expresión común para hacerse examinar por un/el médico ?

Actualmente no es común, sin embargo en la época en que se publico la obra, años 60' del siglo XX, era normal escucharla. Sin duda quedan resquicios, y aún es posible oírla con suerte en ambientes rurales o por personas procedentes de estas áreas que aún mantienen este tipo de expresiones.

Como nota, cuando alguien te dice "hágase ver del médico", es que piensa interiormente que lo que padeces, no es bueno o simplemente es grave y en cierto grado se esta preocupando por tu salud.

Hay que entender que en los pueblos tradicionales las figuras claves eran el *Alcalde*, el *Cura*, el *Maestro de Escuela* y el *Médico*.

---

2.- Si la parte en negrita se dejara en blanco y me pidieran que la completara, probablemente pondría por . ¿También sería correcto?

"Hágase ver **por** el médico".

Si es correcto, sin embargo señala cualidades distintas, cuando dices "Compadre hágase ver del médico", entiendes que se refiere a un médico en concreto. Como he dicho, en los ambientes rurales, en los pueblos, solo existía un médico, "*el médico*" que a todos atiende, denotando cierta cercanía. En esos entornos, todo el mundo sabe quien es "*el médico*".

Si dices, "Compadre, hágase ver **por** el médico", estas hablando de forma impersonal, sobre un médico, quizás especifico, pero que denota no conocer mucho y que puede estar ubicado en el mismo lugar, en el pueblo de al lado o a 50 km. Encierra la idea de cualquier médico en general. En ese caso, desde mi punto de vista es más apropiado decir, "Compadre, hágase ver por un médico", sin especificar nada en el contexto que indique cierta vinculación, ubicación o cercanía con ese doctor (un médico cualquiera o especifico de esa especialidad que atienda en general a esa dolencia).

---

3.- ¿Es esta construcción hacerse V de N generalmente aplicable a get oneself V-ed by N, o el uso de de es específico de esta expresión?

Esta pregunta ya esta contestada, el uso del "de", es especifico de estas expresiones en la que hay cierta preocupación por el cuido o miramiento del enfermo.

" Compadre, hágase ver del médico" (Compadre, hágase ver de "el médico"), es lo mismo que decir, "deja que te examine el médico", refiriéndose con "el médico", al médico del pueblo, o a alguien que conocen, denotando cierto aprecio de quien lo dice por el cuidado del enfermo, en este caso el compadre, en un ambiente donde todo es más cercano. " Compadre, hágase ver del dentista", es dejar entrever una preocupación, intentando de forma indirecta convencer, "Compañero, déjese cuidar por el dentista". " Compadre, hágase ver del cura", viene a decir, "Amigo, estas en las últimas y deberías llamar al cura del pueblo, Pedro, que todos conocen".

Distinto decir, "yo que tu me haría mirar por el médico", es algo más impersonal, más general y distante.

Esta expresión o formula no vale para otras.

- "Hacerse cocinar una lubina", se sobrentiende que has mandado que alguien te prepare o te cocine una lubina.
- "Hacerse de una lubina", " Hacerse de una pistola", significa que por algún medio has conseguido una lubina, una pistola... La has comprado, alguien te la dio, te la encontraste, la robaste...
- "Hacerse el sueco"
- "Hacerse de rogar"
- "Hacerse cargo de"
- Hacerse convidar por el alcalde de Málaga. Significa que planificaste, urdiste o ingeniaste algo para que el alcalde de Málaga te invitara a un evento.

---

4.- ¿También funciona con un nombre propio? (Tengo la sensación de que no).

Hágase ver del doctor García.

Puedes decirlo y se te entenderá sin problemas, sin embargo en este caso, es mejor utilizar la preposición "por". "**Hágase ver por el doctor García**".

Se entiende que el doctor García es especialista o el más capacitado para la dolencia que aflige al enfermo, denotando en la frase cierto carácter imperativo, no hay opciones, pero ya estaríamos en un ámbito más amplio, por ejemplo en una consulta, en el hospital de una ciudad o en un contexto cerrado de un pueblo donde pueden existir varios médicos y referido hacia un forastero que no conoce al doctor García.